# Simple TCP server and client communication via public ip

Tags: sockets

Am using Netgear dgn1000 router and just planning to execute a server-client program over internet. 
I switched off windows firewall. Allowed DMZ in router. Also Disabled antivirus in both the system. I don't know what else i got to do.?
Please do help

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled port forwarding to the PC that the server is running on?

Comment: Ya port forwarding is ON. I have even enabled DMZ, ie. forwarding all ports to server